# Sharepoint 2013 .NET CSOM CamlQuery Join

Tags: sharepoint-addin, caml, client-object-model, .net

I am unable to create a working query with join in my .net csom application. I was using this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx

here is my code:

```
 ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);
 Web web = context.Web;
 var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Esemény");

 CamlQuery cq = new CamlQuery();
 cq.ViewXml= @"<View>
                   <ViewFields>
                       <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                   </ViewFields>
                   <ProjectedFields>
                       <Field Name='PartnerLookupTitle' Type='Lookup' List='PartnerLookup' ShowField='Title' />
                   </ProjectedFields>
                   <Joins>
                       <Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='PartnerLookup'>
                           <Eq>
                               <FieldRef Name='Partner' RefType='ID' />
                               <FieldRef List='Partner' Name='ID' />
                           </Eq>
                       </Join>
                   </Joins>
               </View>";

ListItemCollection lista =  list.GetItems(cq);
context.Load(lista);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I get an exception from the server: "Value does not fall within the expected range."

If I remove the the ProjectedFields and Joins part of the CAML query it works:(

---

Ok. I could create a working query:

```
                @"<View>

                    <ViewFields>
                      <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                      <FieldRef Name='Partner'/>
                      <FieldRef Name='PartnerLookupTitle'/> //new code
                    </ViewFields>

                    <ProjectedFields>
                        <Field Name='PartnerLookupTitle' Type='Lookup' List='PartnerLookup' ShowField='Title' />
                    </ProjectedFields>
                    <Joins>
                      <Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='PartnerLookup'>
                        <Eq>
                          <FieldRef Name='Partner' RefType='ID' />
                          <FieldRef List='PartnerLookup' Name='ID' />
                        </Eq>
                      </Join>
                    </Joins>

                  </View>";
```

Now I can acces the PartnerLookupTitle field, but still dont get this line of code:

```
<FieldRef List='PartnerLookup' Name='ID' />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your definition for the join is wrong. I think it should be:

```
<Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='PartnerLookup'>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Partner' RefType='ID' />
    <FieldRef List='PartnerLookup' Name='ID' />
  </Eq>
</Join>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tryed to modify my code as you suggested and now it works. I dont get an Exception on ExecuteQuery anymore. Can you please explain me, why should I write PartnerLookup instead Partner. I'm afraid I dont understand. 
I have 2 Lists, called Esemény and Partner
the Esemény list has one lookup field called (also) Partner referring the Partner List.

And now when I'm trying to acces the "PartnerLookupTitle" 

Console.WriteLine(listItem["PartnerLookupTitle"];

I get the Exception: PartnerOrFieldNotInitializedException